# How to execute while loops in C

Tags: c, loops

```
 printf("Please type Y if you want us to compute the monthly Rate for new data and N otherwise: ");
scanf("%c",&ans);

while ((ans!='y') && (ans!='Y') && (ans!='n') && (ans!='N')){
        printf("Please type Y if you want us to compute the monthly Rate for new data and N otherwise: ");
        scanf("%c",&ans);}

if (ans == 'N' || ans == 'n'){
    printf("Thank you Please visit us again");}
else if (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
```

While executing this if i enter an n or y it works the right way but if i enter something that isnt an n or y the output lets me input another value but instead of it saying Please type Y if you want us to compute the monthly Rate for new data and N otherwise: it says that twice and i cannot figure out why it would say it twice.

Comment: You seem to be missing some `{}` there.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&ans);}` --> `scanf(" %c",&ans);}`

Comment: Indent your program properly. Compile it with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use a debugger** (`gdb`) e.g. to run it step by step. And test the result of `scanf`

Comment: do some google searches on `scanf` and dirty input buffers... if you enter _"x<enter>"_, your `scanf` will only read the _"x"_ from the buffer, leaving the _"\n"_ (enter) in place. The next time around, `\n` will be read, resulting in the behavior you see. I've explained this in more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144227/c-how-to-handle-user-input-in-a-while-loop)